Speech-to-text Audio query. How to prevent Streamlit from reprocessing audio input on every state change or user interaction with Streamlit app
I'm building a Streamlit chat application with audio recording capabilities using audiorecorder. I'm encountering an issue where my audio processing code runs on every state change or interaction, even when no new audio is recorded.
Code:
from audiorecorder import audiorecorder
import streamlit as st
from langchain_core.messages import AIMessage, HumanMessage
from src.speech2text import speech2text
import os

# Initialize chat history
if "chat_history" not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state.chat_history = [
        AIMessage(content="Initial message"),
    ]

# User input methods
user_query = st.chat_input("Ask a question...")
audio = audiorecorder(start_prompt="", stop_prompt="", pause_prompt="", show_visualizer=False)

# Process user input
if user_query or len(audio) > 0:
    if len(audio) > 0:  # This condition triggers on every Streamlit rerun
        audio.export("audio_query.wav", format="wav")
        with st.chat_message("Human"):
            transcribed_text = speech2text("audio_query.wav")
            st.session_state.chat_history.append(HumanMessage(content=transcribed_text))
            user_query = transcribed_text
            os.remove("audio_query.wav")
    
    elif user_query:
        st.session_state.chat_history.append(HumanMessage(content=user_query))
    else:
        st.stop()

    with st.chat_message("AI"):
        response_container = st.empty()
        response_text = ""

        try:
            with st.spinner("Generating response..."):
                full_response, chunks, urls = rag(user_query, llm_choice, api_key)

            with st.spinner("Generating audio..."):
                audio_file = text2speech(remove_emojis(full_response), 
                             filename="audio_response.mp3")
            if audio_file:
                autoplay_audio("audio_response.mp3")

Problem:

Every time I interact with any element in my Streamlit app (clicking buttons, submitting feedback, etc.), the if len(audio) > 0 check runs again
This causes unnecessary audio processing and file operations
The audio processing should only run when new audio is actually recorded

Expected Behavior:

Audio processing should only trigger when new audio is actually recorded
Other interactions with the app shouldn't trigger the audio processing logic

What I've Tried:

Using session state to track audio status (but unsure of the correct approach)
The issue seems related to Streamlit's reactive rerun behavior

Question:

How can I modify my code to only process audio when new audio is actually recorded?
What's the proper way to handle audio state persistence in Streamlit?

Any help would be appreciated!
